# Display value based on condition - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to update one of the columns in the screenshot shown below based on a condition referring to counter column (Column F).

For example, if counter = 0, then column G should be blank, else it should take value from appointment column from the above cell.

Referring to the image below, 
Cell G2 will be blank since counter = 0
Cell G3 should display value from B2 and H3 shall display C3
Cell G7 shall display should display value from cell B6 as they are all link to the same load (cell A6 has the load number)
Similarly cells G8 - G10 should also display value from B6.

[image]

Could anyone help me with the excel formula for the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add "=IF($F2=0,"",IF($F2=1,B1,G1))" in G2 and Drag Down and Left.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this formula in cell `G2` and drag this down and across column `G` and `H`.

```
=IF($F2=0,"",B1)
```